# Fasttext train function, when called from c code, reads all words, but not number of words is incorrect

Tags: c++, go, cgo, fasttext

currently I am developing fasttext go binding, I am stacked with the problem while training on the same file

from cgo code:

```bash
go test -run ^TestTrain$ -v                                                                                    
=== RUN   TestTrain
Read 1M words
Number of words:  14339
Number of labels: 128
```

from fasttext cli tool:

```bash
$ fasttext supervised -input test_data/train -output test_data/context -lr 0.1 -epoch 10 -wordNgrams 2 -thread 10
Read 1M words
Number of words:  49914
Number of labels: 128
```

my cgo realization look like this:

```cpp
extern "C" {

    fasttext::FastText ft_model;
    bool ft_initialized = false;

int ft_train(const char* model_name, const char* input, const char* output, int epoch, int word_ngrams, int thread, float lr)
    {
        fasttext::Args args_object;

        if (strcmp(model_name, "supervised") == 0) { 
            args_object.model = fasttext::model_name::sup;
        } else if (strcmp(model_name, "cbow") == 0) {
            args_object.model = fasttext::model_name::cbow;
        } else if (strcmp(model_name, "skipgram") == 0) {
            args_object.model = fasttext::model_name::sg;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
            
        args_object.input = input;
        args_object.output = output;
        args_object.epoch = epoch;
        args_object.wordNgrams = word_ngrams;
        args_object.thread = thread;
        args_object.lr = lr;

        ft_model.train(args_object);
        ft_initialized = true;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

so as I can research fasttext has two train fuctions, one called from [macro](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/main/src/main.cc#L358) and another is [method](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/main/src/fasttext.cc#L743) of fasttext class, but they are pretty similar to me as I'm not a professional as c++, can anyone provide some help?

UPD: I use function from macro which create fasttext instance and call the train method, like this:

```cpp
int train(const char* model_name, const char* input, const char* output, int epoch, int word_ngrams, int thread, float lr) {
        const std::vector<std::string> args = {
            "fasttext",
            std::string(model_name),
            "-input",
            std::string(input),
            "-output",
            std::string(output),
            "-epoch",
            std::to_string(epoch),
            "-wordNgrams",
            std::to_string(word_ngrams),
            "-thread",
            std::to_string(thread),
            "-lr",
            std::to_string(lr)
        };

        fasttext::Args a = fasttext::Args();
        a.parseArgs(args);
        std::shared_ptr<fasttext::FastText> fasttext = std::make_shared<fasttext::FastText>();
        std::string outputFileName;

        if (a.hasAutotune() &&
            a.getAutotuneModelSize() != fasttext::Args::kUnlimitedModelSize) {
            outputFileName = a.output + ".ftz";
        } else {
            outputFileName = a.output + ".bin";
        }
        std::ofstream ofs(outputFileName);
        if (!ofs.is_open()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(
                outputFileName + " cannot be opened for saving.");
        }
        ofs.close();
        if (a.hasAutotune()) {
            fasttext::Autotune autotune(fasttext);
            autotune.train(a);
        } else {
            fasttext->train(a);
        }
        fasttext->saveModel(outputFileName);
        fasttext->saveVectors(a.output + ".vec");
        if (a.saveOutput) {
            fasttext->saveOutput(a.output + ".output");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

It solved my problem, but I still do not understand what is the difference between those two approaches?